# How to centralize validation rules in Asp.Net MVC 4?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Below is a sample scenario:**

User can create and/or update a policy online. While updating, user may change the start date of the policy. Condition is, if policy start date has passed (means smaller than today) then, start date can't be changed, else it can be changed.

**My problem is:**

There can be 5 types of policies and each has some common properties as well as some uncommon properties. Now I want to validate those properties against my business rules (like the sample) from a centralized place (may be class or whatever). But I am stuck on how/where to start.

**Currently trying:**

Currently I am validating those properties inside Controllers and sometimes inside Views but that is requiring lots of manual work and code maintenance will be troublesome in future. Can someone please give some idea.

**Environment:**

Asp.Net MVC4, Razor, VS2013

Comment: Use validation attributes appplied to your model properties so you get both client and server side validation. For example for validating the `StartDate` you could use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` attribute